# How to query a name in a column which has exactly 2 'a' in any position

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Suppose I've a table EMP which contains, empno, ename, etc anything. Now I've to query the ename of emp where there are 2  'a' in the name.

I tried the following

```
select ename from emp where ename like "%a%a";
```

This query return me with more than 2 'a', due to the courtesy of '%'.

So kindly pitch in!!

Comment: MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: `WHERE LENGTH(ename) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ename, 'a', '')) = 2`.

Comment: *I've to query the ename of emp where there are 2 `'a'` in the name. I tried the following- select ename from emp `where ename like "%a%a"`;* You search only the values where one of `'a'` is the last char.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a condition that excludes cases with more than 2 occurrences:

```
where ename like '%a%a%'
and   ename not like '%a%a%a%'
```

Comment: @AnandaKrishnanS . . . This is the simplest method and works across all databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP_COUNT` as following:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(ENAME, 'a', 1, 'i') = 2 -- case insensitive
-- REGEXP_COUNT(ENAME, 'a') = 2 - if you want case sensitive comparision
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL or MariaDB version that supports `REGEXP_REPLACE`, you can also do like this:

```
SELECT ename FROM emp
WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(na,'[b-zB-Z]',''))=2;
```

Omitting the character `a` or `A` from the replace condition here `'[b-zB-Z]'` then use `LENGTH` to define only show result when `a` or `A` occur twice.

Otherwise, I've tested @Akina's method (in the comment) and it works very well regardless of any MySQL/MariaDB version.

Answer (score 0):

### Display the employee with exactly 2 A's in there name

```sql
select * from employee
where length(emp_name) - length(replace(upper(emp_name), 'A', '')) = 2;
```

Comment: replace(upper(emp_name), "A", ''): In this step, the replace function is used to remove all occurrences of the letter 'A' (either uppercase or lowercase) from the name. The result is the name without any 'A's.

Comment: That comment should be in the answer. Edit your answer to improve it thus. And please don't use double quotes for string literals. Standard SQL string literals require single quotes.